# Why a PHP boolean expression becomes false when assigned to a variable

Tags: php, drupal, variable-assignment, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I'm seeing a very strange behaviour in a PHP script when assigning the result of evaluating a boolean expression into a variable.

When I evaluate this code...

```
  <?php var_dump($is_admin or ($logged_in and ($user->uid === $uid))); ?>
```

... the result is:

```
  bool(true)
```

But, when I assign the boolean expression to a variable, such as...

```
 <?php $can_edit = $is_admin or ($logged_in and ($user->uid === $uid)); ?>
 <?php var_dump($can_edit); ?>
```

... the result becomes:

```
 bool(false)
```

What is causing this behaviour? I'm using PHP 5.3.10 and Drupal 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precedence. `or` has lower precedence than `=`, so you're just assigning the value of `is_admin` to the variable.

Either put parentheses around the expression:

```
$can_edit = ($is_admin or ($logged_in and ($user->uid === $uid)));
```

or use `||` and `&&`, which have higher precedence:

```
$can_edit = $is_admin || ($logged_in && ($user->uid === $uid));
```

Usually `or` is usually used for separating actions, as in:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT ...") or log_error($db->error);
```

while `||` is used when computing boolean expressions. This is the reason for the different precedences (you don't want to set `$stmt` to the result of `log_error()`).

Comment: Perfectly explained! Thank you!